# RMS switch current in boost converter

Tags: switches, power-electronics, boost

I'm struck in calculating the I(switch,rms) in boost converter. Average current through diode = average o/p current , also average current through the inductor = average current through the source. From this I drew the following waveform. So,
[image: equation]
[image: waveform]

**EDIT**
This was the part of the following question.

> A DC-DC boost converter, as shown in the figure below, is used to
>   boost 360V to 400 V, at a power of 4 kW. All devices are ideal.
>   Considering continuous inductor current, the rms current in the solid
>   state switch (S), in ampere, is _________.
>   [image: diagram]

Comment: Hint: the average current is just the size of the area under the curve trace.

Comment: + averaged over the whole cycle

Comment: The op is talking about RMS and not average dudes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From first principles for a waveform repeating over a period Tp being a current rising from Ii to Ii+Id.

\begin{equation}
I_{RMS}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{Tp}\int_0^{Tp} (I_i+\frac{I_d.t}{Tp})².dt}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=\sqrt{\frac{1}{Tp}\int_0^{Tp} (I_i^2+\frac{2.I_i.I_d.t}{Tp}+\frac{I_d².t^2}{Tp²}).dt}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=\sqrt {\frac{1}{Tp}(I_i^2.t+\frac{I_i.I_d.t^2}{Tp}+\frac{I_d².t^3}{3Tp²})_{t=0}^{t=Tp}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=\sqrt{ \frac{1}{Tp}(I_i^2.Tp+\frac{I_i.I_d.Tp^2}{Tp}+\frac{I_d².Tp^3}{3Tp²})}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I_{RMS}=\sqrt {I_i^2+I_i.I_d+\frac{I_d²}{3}}
\end{equation}

If instead you consider this to be a ramp rising from i1 to i2 substitute i1 for Ii and i2-i1 for Id and you get

\begin{equation}
I_{RMS}=\sqrt {i1^2+i1.(i2-i1)+\frac{(i2-i1)^2}{3}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=\sqrt {i1.i2+\frac{(i2^2-2i1.i2+i1^2)}{3}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=\sqrt {\frac{(i2^2+i1.i2+i1^2)}{3}}
\end{equation}

This is independent of time and i1 and i2 are interchangable so where you have a ramp going from i1 to i2 and then back to i1 in one period this is your result and it is independent of duty cycle.

Now you need to average the result from above out over time.

To average two different RMS currents over a longer period (clue one of these can be zero).
Say we have Irms1 for t1 and Irms2 for t2.

\begin{equation}
I_{RMS}=\sqrt{\frac{I_{RMS1}^2.t_1+I_{RMS2}^2.t_2}{t1+t2}}
\end{equation}

So where you have a ramp going from i1 to i2 for t1 and no current for t2 we get.

\begin{equation}
I_{RMS}=\sqrt {\frac{t1}{t1+t2}.\frac{(i2^2+i1.i2+i1^2)}{3}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Time period of function is T. So the first equation must be divided with T instead of Tp.

Comment: Division by Tp is the mean part of RMS and I defined Tp as the period.

Comment: Top equation is for the RMS for the ramp part of the waveform  and I do not think it is the same as Andy aka's answer. Use bottom equation to average over a longer time period.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is 3.51 amperes RMS.

The problem doesn't seem to be
asking for ramp effects, since there's no mention of allowable
output ripple or switching frequency.  So, it's safe to assume 
that the switching frequency is so high that the current through 
the inductor can be considered constant.

The duty cycle, the part of the time that the switch is on, is 10%.
When it's on, the voltage across the inductor is 360.  When it's
off the voltage is -40 (i.e. 360-400).  So it follows that the off time
must be 9 times the on time.

From the duty cycle it follows that 90% of the inductor current goes
to the load.  The load current is 10 amps. (4kW at 400 V). The inductor 
current is therefore 10/.9 amps.

During the 10% of the time the switch is on the current through it
is 10/.9 amps. The RMS current is the square root of the inductor
current squared times the duty cycle.

Comment: You are quite correct. Both Andy and I missed the point of the question. Upvoted

Comment: How did one of the answers above give a numerical value (3.51A) without knowing the switching frequency? You cannot eleminate the switching period from the rms current equation.

Comment: @JakubGrochowski The integration can be done over any number of cycles (one to infinity) and the time drops out. The duty cycle remains, or if starting with pulse width and period, the ratio can be taken to obtain this just as well. In general, RMS is a frequency-independent measure, the "mean" of RMS is taken over a long enough time period to get the DC (time independent) equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm struck in calculating the I(switch,rms) in boost converter

[image]

\$I_{rms}= \sqrt{d_1\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot (I_1^2+I_1\cdot I_2+I_2^2)+ (1-d_1)\cdot I_0}\$

T is assumed to be 1 and hence \$d_1\$ becomes the duty cycle fraction.

For your example, the \$I_0\$ term can be ignored hence the formula reduces to: -

\$I_{rms}= \sqrt{d_1\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot (I_1^2+I_1\cdot I_2+I_2^2)}\$

Note - I did get in a pickle with this on previous edits and thanks to @oceanp for provoking me to rethink. Pictures and formula taken from [**here**](http://www.kpap.net/notes/item.php?id=RMSofKeyWaveforms).

Comment: This method is valid. Thanks a lot. Could you give a hint on how to solve the question?

Comment: Which part of my answer relating to finding the rms current didn't you follow?

Comment: RMS = √(RECTANGLE^2+SAWTOOTH^2) is only true for uncorrelated waveforms or a few other special cases

Comment: @oceanp yes I realized that a few minutes ago and I'm going to fix it or dump it. Darn, I'd hoped to get away without anyone noticing LOL.

Comment: @oceanp I think it's fixed now!!

Comment: @Andy sorry the problem is not the time averaging the problem is that the integral of a squared function is only equal to the sum of the squares of the elements of the function if they are uncorrelated aka don't overlap in time. There are exceptions that do not apply in this case. There are sometimes things you wish you never got into :)

Comment: @oceanp in my changes I have calculated the RMS based on the sawtooth waveform AND a permanent DC shift thus this value would be correct if the DC existed in the time period from t1 to T. I've then corrected for this by multiplying the overly excessive squared RMS value (the power) by the duty cycle and then taken the square root to return to RMS. I do think this works now but maybe you are right?

Comment: @Andy Correct if the square wave was shifted away from the sawtooth. Lets take an instantaneous current on the square say 5A and say at this instant the current on the sawtooth was 1A. The power contribution of this would be (1+5)² = 36 not 1²+5²=26.

Comment: @oceanp Yes I agree on that but I've dumped the square bit now and I'm just concentrating on DC plus AC power then lowering the power by the duty and then square rooting but I was wrong yesterday and I could still be wrong (I suppose LOL).

Comment: Sorry edit overlapped post.

Comment: @oceanp I'm not using the "synchronous" square wave idea any more; I'm calculating power based on the RMS of the sawtooth in the presense of permanent DC. Then I'm reducing the power by the duty cycle. Then I'm square rooting to obtain RMS.

Comment: Divide inside of square root by T dude.

Comment: This is now the same as my answer just expressed slightly differently you only have to add the time averaging over T. Your source normalises their equations to T=1 thinking is good.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the comparison, Your formula doesn't have mention of t1 or T but I've upvoted as respect for the provocation I needed.